# Why Bootstrap is not working with Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I installed Bootstrap and jQuery. I added js and css paths in angular.json. I exit and run server again but still bootstrap not working. Can you help me to fix this issue?

Here is the form and some buttons but bootstrap is not working.

[image]

I realized styles.js is missing when I run server. I am not sure if it is the problem or not!? And I don't know how to solve it

Here is when I run Angular server:

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 18.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 12.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 2.62 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-09-14T08:40:22.944Z - Hash: ca7f2c17673277a29876 - Time: 5631ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.
```

angular.json:

```
     {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "registration": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/registration",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "registration:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "registration:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "registration:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"    
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
              
            ],
            "scripts": [
              
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "registration:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "registration:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "registration"
}
```

Comment: Can you put your whole angular.json file?

Comment: also add template code or create one sample stackblitz

Comment: What you mean by template code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that the problem is that you have put:

```
      "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
          
        ],
        "scripts": [
          
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

Under the `"test"` project, you should put it inside your `"build"` options.